# Using multiple return statements in a for loop

Tags: javascript, arrays

Here is my code:

```
var looptimesfrarray_TEST = reversegridarrayFORUNDEFINE(st_time_formated_TEST);

for (var c = 0; c < obj.length - 1; c++) {
    if (looptimesfrarray_TEST[c] === undefined) {
        var mycharttime = Highcharts.dateFormat('%H:%M:%P', this.value);
        return timsesubstringforXaxis(mycharttime);
    } else {
        return timsesubstringforgrid(looptimesfrarray_TEST[c]);
    }
}
```

I would like to return return multiple results based on the `if`/`else` in the `for` loop, but my `c` is not increasing in the loop, so it gives me `c = 0` every time. I tried to use `break` and `continue`, but they didn’t work. How can I do this?

Comment: `return` breaks the function immediately.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Returning from a function ends the execution of that function. It means "I have a result! I'm done!".

Each time you go around the loop you either return or you return.

So the function gets exited the first time you go around the loop, no matter what.

If you want to loop over all the values, then you need to return *after the loop has finished*. Usually you'll want to collect data in a variable as you go around the loop and then return the variable.

Answer (score 0):

@Quentin already give an explanation, and I just show a code, how you could collect all results for each element in array and return this array from a function:

```
var res = [];
var looptimesfrarray_TEST = reversegridarrayFORUNDEFINE(st_time_formated_TEST);
   for (var c = 0; c < obj.length - 1; c++) {
   if (looptimesfrarray_TEST[c] === undefined) {

   var mycharttime = Highcharts.dateFormat('%H:%M:%P', this.value);

   res.push(timsesubstringforXaxis(mycharttime));

   }
   else {

   res.push(timsesubstringforgrid(looptimesfrarray_TEST[c]));


   }
 }
return res;
```